# Next.js dynamic route loading an inexistent script causing 404

Tags: next.js

To use dynamic routes I have created a `pages/[slug].js` page and I link to it as recommended:

```
<Link href="/shop/[slug]" as={`/shop/${item.slug}`}>
  <a>{item.title}</a>
</Link>
```

I have followed the Next.js documentation:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes
- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes

The link and the page work as expected locally after running `next dev`, however in production (or after building the app and running `next start` locally), after navigating to the dynamic route, a non-existent script is systematically loaded. It doesn't crash the app but it does generate a request with a 404 status code.
The script is loaded from `/_next/static/___/pages/shop/example-page.js`.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was happening because of dummy placeholder links on the page: `<Link href="#"><a>Home</a></Link>`. Replacing them with working links solved the problem.